# E-commerce - Full MVC with Laravel vs Next.JS for views

Tags: reactjs, laravel, next.js, e-commerce

I need advice please.

Do any of you know Next.js well? (or its competitor Nuxt.JS).

In a week or two, I'm going to attack a "big" 100% tailor-made E-commerce website.

This site must be efficient and above all **very well referenced**. So I can't just use React.JS (because the HTML code has to be generated on the server side).

I am hesitating between:

- Do everything in "full Laravel" (use Blade for views).
- Or to separate my code into 2 parts: Laravel for the API part, and Next.JS for the views part.

Your opinions please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look to the future of application:

When we talk about escalabillity, a separated api (laravel/lumen/nodejs) would be a better option than create a monolitic laravel application because you have freedom to provide the api to one or more regardless applications, and sooner or later you will choose to create another app to do the same thing in other platforms.